# mysql only fetches single row rather than all

Tags: php, mysql

Hello in my php code mysql only fetches 1 result which is in the last rather than all please help me why its doing like this here is my code

```
        $requesthost = "SELECT * FROM tblvhost";
        $reshost = mysql_query($requesthost);
        while($rowhost=mysql_fetch_array($reshost)) {
            $hostvid = $rowhost['vh_id'];
            $hostname = $rowhost['vh_name'];        
        }
```

Comment: What are you doing with $hostvid and $hostname? Looks like you're not using them IN the loop, which means you're overwriting them before you use them for the first time. If I'm wrong, please submit what else is inside the room.

Comment: It reads all rows. It's just that your variables in the while loop are overwritten by every loop. Also please switch to PDO or MySQLi. `Mysql_*` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re overriding the data within each loop iteration:

```
    while($rowhost=mysql_fetch_array($reshost)) {
        $hostvid = $rowhost['vh_id'];    // overwritten
        $hostname = $rowhost['vh_name']; // overwritten       
    }
```

To collect all the data you probably want to append them to an array:

```
    $hostvid = array();
    $hostname = array();
    while($rowhost=mysql_fetch_array($reshost)) {
        $hostvid[] = $rowhost['vh_id'];    // insert into array
        $hostname[] = $rowhost['vh_name']; // insert into array       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwrite your variables in your loop. Store them into an array.

```
while ($rowhost = mysql_fetch_array($reshost)) {
    $row[] = array(
        'hostvid' => $rowhost['vh_id'],
        'hostname' => $rowhost['vh_name']
    );
}
var_dump($row);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a good question plus its a learning curve for the ones that are new that run into these types of issues

you're code

```
$requesthost = "SELECT * FROM tblvhost";
$reshost = mysql_query($requesthost);
while($rowhost=mysql_fetch_array($reshost)) {
    $hostvid = $rowhost['vh_id'];
    $hostname = $rowhost['vh_name'];        
}
```

looks good, but what you are doing with or how are you applying hostvid? or hostname? you can just do

```
    while($rowhost=mysql_fetch_array($reshost)) {
        $rowhost['vh_id'];    //do something with the var that's getting mysql field data
        $rowhost['vh_name'];  //same applies here. using $rowhost will continue to to provide data depending on what you have in the db. so you're OK.       
    }
```

if you want to store the data in an array for later use outside of the loop you can follow what @mudasobwa posted. good answer.